# Numeric data type formatting after SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, numeric

I've got another issue, I have a SQL Server database in which I insert data using `SqlCommand`, one of the columns is numeric, but when I read this column back with this code:

```
 zcena1.Text = precti.GetDecimal(4).ToString();
```

the inserted button 123 is inserted as 123,00 (which is ok)

When I read it back it gives me back 123,00 is there any way to make it read like 123.00? Can I replace comma with dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
zcena1.Text = precti.GetDecimal(4).ToString().Replace(',', '.');
```

Comment: This approach works well for a specific case. But best practices should be adopted, so if you application is going to run at different countries of continental Europe, you'll want to keep the comma instead of the dot. And that where the localization shows it's strength

Answer (score 1):

you should try working localized, look for

```
Decimal.Parse (String, IFormatProvider)
```